# OrgMode, how to pass options to LaTex listings?

Tags: org-mode, latex

When I export an Emacs OrgMode buffer like:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{listings}
* How to pass options to LaTex listings?
#+ATTR_LATEX: :options [numbers=left]
#+BEGIN_SRC sh
echo "hello world"
#+END_SRC
```

the exported LaTex buffer does not contain the `numbers=left` but the default `numbers=none`.

```
...snip
\usepackage{listings}
\date{\today}
\title{demo-listings-2}
\hypersetup{
  pdfkeywords={},
  pdfsubject={},
  pdfcreator={Emacs 24.5.1 (Org mode 8.2.10)}}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\section{How to pass options to LaTex listings?}
\label{sec-1}
\lstset{language=sh,label= ,caption= ,numbers=none}
\begin{lstlisting}
echo "hello world"
\end{lstlisting}
% Emacs 24.5.1 (Org mode 8.2.10)
\end{document}
```

I expected the `ATTR_LATEX: :options [numbers=left]` to override the default value.

The only LaTex configuration I have in the `.emacs`file is:

```
(require 'ox-latex)
(setq org-latex-listings t)
```

Any idea of what I am missing or doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `#+ATTR_LATEX: :options numbers=left` (without the []). More options can be separated by commas: `:options numbers=left, captionpos=b`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I tried your suggestion, but the result is the same. I am not able to override the default value.

Comment: I have `Emacs 25.3.2 (Org mode 9.1.2)`, maybe you could consider to upgrade.

Comment: Thanks again! I tried with a default Ubuntu 17.10 distro, `{Emacs 25.2.2 (Org mode 8.2.10)}}` and got the same results. I upgraded the Org mode to `{Emacs 25.2.2 (Org mode 9.1.2)}` and now it works. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

For numbered listings specifically, you'll need to add "-n" to your source block's header:

```
#+begin_src sh -n
echo "hello world"
#+end_src
```

Exports as:

1 `echo "hello world"`

Comment: This does work for me.  I had been trying to include line numbers for my source code blocks in my Org mode's exports to LaTex, and then to PDF.